# C++ - Array Math

Tags: c++, c, arrays, math

I am trying to do this equation into C++

```
root[0] = root [0] - F(root[0])/ root[0] - root[1] * root[0] - root[2] * root[0] - root[3]
```

in this examples there are only 3, changes by user input.

The program is trying to solve polynomial equations hopefully this is enough information.

I have got the top of the Equation work here is what I am came up with:

```
complex<double> top, bottom;
top = (complex<double>)coefficientArray[1] * (pow (rootArray[0], Degree));
rootArray[0] = rootArray[0] - (top/bottom);
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, and what is the problem exactly

Comment: Also, if you're using C++, please don't tag as C.

Comment: I am trying to make a Polynomial Solver,  I need the equation at the top in c++. say for example the user enters 99 as the root it does this equation 98 times and times each answer by one and other.

Format of the question is:

Root[0]-root[1]   Root[0]-root[2]   .... Root[0]-root[72]  

Then times the answer of each by one and other.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  It is more a math question that you are trying to program.  Before you can program something, you must first understand what it is you are doing (e.g. if you are writing a program to solve 0's for binomials, you first need to know the Quadratic Method before you can program it).

Answer (score 2):

Solving `linear` equations is alot faster using:

1. The coefficient matrix
2. An unknown variable matrix (to which you will solve)
3. The answer matrix

To find the roots of higher grade equations -with an approximation error- you should use the
 `Newton-Raphson` method.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is what I am trying todo I have done the rest of the equation just cant get this bit I have alto of code done but there's alot

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is something like

```
int highestPower = // whatever the user input says is the highest power
for (int i=1; i<=highestPower; i++) {
  bottom += root[i] * pow(root[0], i);
}
```

Comment: Most naive approach ever.